# What does $this->{$key} mean in PHP?

Tags: php

What are the differences between following codes?

```
$this->idKey
$this->$idKey
$this->{$idKey}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reads the `idkey` property of the `$this` object:

```
$this->idKey;
```

Reads the variable property name of the `$this` object (`example` in this case) so `$this->example`:

```
$idKey = 'example';
$this->$idKey;
```

Same as above (`$this->example`), but with less ambiguity (similar to adding parentheses to control operand order, and useful in some cases):

```
$idKey = 'example';
$this->{$idKey};
```

A case where this may add clarity or control the order:

```
$this->{$idKey['key']};
$this->{$idKey}['key'];
```

Answer (score 2):

> **$this->idKey**

This is how you would access an object property in php

```
class Car {
 //member properties
 var $color;

  function printColor(){
    echo $this->color; //accessing the member property color.
  }
}
```

> **$this->$idKey**

This can be used when the property name itself is stored in a variable

```
$attribute ='color'

$this->$attribute // is equivalent to $this->color
```

> **$this->{'$idKey'}**

Is an explicit form of above expression, but it also serves one more purpose, accessing properties of a class that is **Not** a [valid variable name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

```
$a = array('123' => '123', '123foo' => '123foo');
$o = (object)$a;
echo $o->123foo; // error
```

So you could use the *curly brace* expression to resolve this

```
$a = array('123' => '123', '123foo' => '123foo');
$o = (object)$a;
echo $o->{'123foo'}; // OK!
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->idKey` is the property `idKey` of the scoped object.

`$this->$idKey` and `$this->{$idKey}` will give you the same result which is accessing the property named in the value of `$idKey`.

```
class ButtHaver{
    public idKey;
    public buttSize;
}

$b = new ButtHaver();
$b->idKey = 'buttSize';
$b->buttSize = 'Large';
echo $b->idKey; // outputs 'buttSize'
echo $b->$idKey; // outputs 'Large'
echo $b->{$idKey}; // outputs 'Large'
```

the `${$}` syntax is to resolve ambiguity in certain cases like `$$a[1]` to clear up which is the variable you want. `${$a[1]}` for the variable named in the value in the array and `${$a}[1]` for the array named in the variable $a.

You can read all about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php